# Mouse missing inside the mobile device emulator in Chrome dev tools, how to get it back?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, device-emulation

I'm not sure if something just changed with dev tools with an update or if I accidentally pressed something on the settings but I no longer get the circle mouse indicator inside the mobile emulator. Is there a way to get it back?

Steps to replicate:

1. Open dev tools (press F12 key)
2. Toggle the device tool bar (Ctrl + Shift + M, the focused window must be the dev tool bar for this shortcut to work or just click the device icon)
3. Select "iPhone 6" from the drop down
4. Mouse into the mobile emulator window
5. In my case the mouse disappears, how to get it back so I know where I'm clicking?

Comment: Sounds like a bug https://crbug.com/656915. The suggested temporary workaround is to enable mouse pointer trails in control panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So not a real solution but the workaround was to switch monitors. Apparently if you are using a dual monitor set up switching the dev tools from the problem monitor to the other cases the mouse to show up. Don't think this is a dev tools problem but more of an issue with how multi monitor set ups work. I am on windows so maybe windows specific.

Comment: Happens on OSX as well

Comment: I am definitely experiencing this on windows as well. If I move the window to monitor #1 then the cursor appears normally. If I move it to monitor #2 then it is invisible. Seems like a bug in dev tools though, since the cursor normally appears to work fine on both monitors. It only fails when entering the device viewport.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Intel Graphics. Just go here

> Intel Display settings > General > [Display Name] > Quantization Range

Change it from "default" to "full" and the problem will disappear!